# FormData() - JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, performance

Until i needed to upload a file throw AJAX, i never knew there was a method like "FormData()" that POST all values of the FORM and some more.

I tested and worked perfect for file upload, but i could also send the other POST DATA, and this become even better.

Can i always use this for all my forms throw AJAX even if i don't have a file to upload? Or there is a downsizing of doing this other the upload the file?

In terms of performance, it's better to get the value of the input and send as data, or can i just use this to simplify?

The only information i could find about this, was for file upload, and not general use of this method.

Code Example:

```
<form id="theForm">
<<input id="test" type="text" name="test" placeholder="test" required="">
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="uploadFile" placeholder="uploadFile" required="">
<input id="submitFile" type="submit">
</form> 

$("#submitFile").on("click",function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($('#theForm')[0]);

    $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "inc/upload.php",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
           beforeSend: function() {

               //Do Something 
         },

        })
        .done(function()
        {

        //Do Something 


        });


});
```

Thank you,
Kind Regards!

Comment: `FormData()` isn't a jQuery method, it's a Javascript object. for jQuery you can use `$("#form").serialize()`. You can read more about `FormData` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `FormData()` for any form. The only downside is that it's a more verbose format. It uses the `multipart/form-data` encoding rather than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Instead of the terse syntax:

```
name1=value1&name2=value2&...
```

the form parameters will be sent as something like:

```
--Delimiter
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name1"

value1
--Delimiter
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name2"

value2
--Delimiter
...
```

Where `Delimiter` is a long, random string.

jQuery has a method `$("#theForm").serialize()` that will return the URL-encoded string. This can be used for any form that doesn't contain a `file` input.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Thought serialize() only worked for GET and not POST, but i'm guessing i was wrong.

Comment: Yes, it works for either. And if you pass an ordinary object to `$.ajax` it will automatically be serialized into URL-encoded format.